# How to interactively remove all directories matching given criteria?

Tags: shell, find, xargs

My script below has two problems:

- The script stops after first matched directory
- `rm -i` is not quite interactive

What are my incorrect assumptions that make it fail? How can I fix it?

```
ls -1A | xargs -d "\n" \
sh -c '(find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    -name "*.flac" | read 2>/dev/null) || rm -ri "$1"'
```

Comment: Since you say that your script doesn't quite work, please can you state categorically what it is that you want it to do. (Including a definition of your criteria for deletion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rm`'s stdin (where it reads the prompt answer from) is `/dev/null` (set by GNU xargs, some other xargs implementations would keep it as the pipe from ls).

Your `sh` is getting many arguments at once, but you're only processing one (`$1`).

Also note that the newline character is as valid as any in a file name which is why you generally can't process the output of `ls` reliably.

With `zsh`:

```
for dir (*(ND/)) {
  flacs=($dir/*.flac(ND.))
  (($#flacs)) || rm -ri -- $dir
}
```

Otherwise, you could do:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    find "$dir/." ! -name . -prune -type f -name "*.flac" | read f ||
      rm -ri "$dir"
  done' sh {} +
```